# PDO Binding is not working

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, php-7.1

**At first, I thought Eloquent/Query Builder is broken. The culprit is PDO. I am using MSSQL/SqlSrv**

**PHP Version: 7.1**

**MSSQL 2016**

I am trying to run this query:

```
$results = DB::connection('RF_USER')->select("SELECT username = CAST(id as varchar(255)), password = CAST(password as varchar(255)) FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id=CONVERT(binary, :username)", ["username" => $username]);
```

But it keeps returning me a null array where-as I do have data in my database. id is type BINARY. password too is type binary. How would I fix this issue?

After debugging, I found this:

**When I explicitly state the username like this, which is 'HASSAN'**

```
$results = DB::connection('RF_USER')->select("SELECT username = CAST(id as varchar(255)), password = CAST(password as varchar(255)) FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id=CONVERT(binary, 'HASSAN')");
```

It returns correctly.

However, when I try to bind the username, it doesn't work. I did debug the value of the variable `$username` and it is perfectly correct.

**After hours of debugging, I decided to use plain PDO, and guess what? PDO is the culprit.**

```
    $username = "HASSAN";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username = CAST(id as varchar(255)), password = CAST(password as varchar(255)) FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id=CONVERT(binary, :username)");

    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetch();
```

The above code, is correct, but does not work. And by does not work, I mean, I get an empty result. No result. However, this does:

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username = CAST(id as varchar(255)), password = CAST(password as varchar(255)) FROM tbl_rfaccount WHERE id=CONVERT(binary, 'HASSAN')");

    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I found out that you cannot use binding for values within a function in an SQL query. It's not supported in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

use `DB::raw()` for your select statement.

```
$results = DB::connection('RF_USER')->select(
               DB::raw(
                 "SELECT 
                     username = CAST(id as varchar(255)), 
                     password = CAST(password as varchar(255)) 
                  FROM tbl_rfaccount 
                  WHERE id=CONVERT(binary, :username)", 
                  ["username" => $username]
              )
           );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get two exceptions.

Comment: `SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (SQL: SELECT 
username = CAST(id as varchar(255)), 
password = CAST(password as varchar(255)) 
FROM tbl_rfaccount 
WHERE id=CONVERT(binary, :username))`

Comment: `PDOException
SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error`